# OSGI - missing imported package=org.apache.commons.collections

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-commons, apache-felix

I'm trying to create very simple OSGI bundle with Circular FIFO Buffer. This is the complete source code:  http://www.2shared.com/file/TkLeBBO2/test.html

I created this simple java class:

```
package com.sh_2.test;

import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer;

public class Buffer {

      Buffer fifo = (Buffer) BufferUtils.synchronizedBuffer(new CircularFifoBuffer(200));

}
```

I imported dependency package org.apache.commons.collections. I successfully compiled the code with Netbeans. When I tried to deploy the bundle on Glassfish application server I get this error:

```
Feb 17, 2012 5:40:22 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
/opt/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java
-cp
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish
-Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/jdk1.7.0_01/lib/ext:/opt/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/lib/ext:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Djava.library.path=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-domainname
domain1
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
-instancename
server
-verbose
false
-debug
false
-asadmin-classpath
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain
-upgrade
false
-type
DAS
-domaindir
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
Feb 17, 2012 5:40:22 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 35 msec.
[#|2012-02-17T17:40:32.867+0200|INFO|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12)|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:32.868+0200|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Record begin marker is not a proper value so using default.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:32.868+0200|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Record end marker is not a proper value so using default.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:32.868+0200|WARNING|null|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Log Format field separator is not a character so using default.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.237+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.759+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 205ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.763+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 158ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.765+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 194ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.766+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 86ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.770+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:33.763+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 253ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:36.063+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Started NB_27-api [379]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:36.067+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|CORE10010: Loading application NB_27-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT done in 2,094 ms|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:36.072+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (12) startup time : Felix (8,046ms), startup services(4,094ms), total(12,140ms)|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:40:37.610+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=47;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://Testserver:8686/jndi/rmi://Testserver:8686/jmxrmi|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:16.978+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.util.Version|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:16.987+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:18.023+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 68ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:18.787+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=87;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.36 started in: 3ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:18.934+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:18.936+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console is starting. Please wait.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:22.622+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:22.629+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:22.691+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:22.833+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:22.843+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:23.440+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:23.576+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:24.659+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:24.769+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:24.785+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:24.978+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:24.983+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:25.029+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:25.077+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:32.985+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) for context ''|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:35.059+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|REST00001: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:36.492+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:37.565+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0671: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:37.569+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|CORE10010: Loading application __admingui done in 18,631 ms|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:37.569+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console application is loaded.|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:41.756+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:42.543+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=104;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:41:42.797+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=95;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.433+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.576+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.617+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.849+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Installed com.SH_2.test [406] from reference:file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.852+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.SH_2.test [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.collections)(version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.resume(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.start(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.SH_2.test [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.collections)(version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3443)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:107)
    ... 55 more
|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.882+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.890+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Uninstalled com.SH_2.test [406]|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.894+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=93;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.SH_2.test [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.collections)(version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.SH_2.test [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.collections)(version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3443)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.resume(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.start(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2012-02-17T17:42:08.921+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.SH_2.test [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.collections)(version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))). Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

I seems that there is dependency problem, maybe a bug into apache commons collections package. I tried with older versions of the package but there is no change. Is this OSGI problem or a bug in apache commons package? How I can repair the code?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. The error message (did you read it?) says that there is a missing dependency on the package `org.apache.commons.collections`. You need to install the Commons Collections bundle.

Comment: As you can see in this screenshot I have already done it: http://i42.tinypic.com/14tydl3.png

Comment: That's a screenshot of a Maven pom. It says nothing about what's in your runtime.

Comment: I understand where is my mistake.